# How to loop through data in java enum and print it on vueJS

Tags: java, vue.js, enums

If I have a java enum containing some report data and methods, can I print out the report data in vue cli?

enumExample.java

```
public enum DefaultFormatE {
    Report001    ("Report001",    "HTML",   "ReportName001"),
    Report002    ("Report002",    "PDF",    "ReportName002"),
    Report003    ("Report003",    "XLS",    "ReportName003");

    DefaultFormatE(String reportId, String defaultFormat, String reportName){
        this.reportId = reportId;
        this.defaultFormat = defaultFormat;
        this.reportName = reportName;
    }

    public static String FORMAT_PDF = "PDF";
    public static String FORMAT_EXCEL = "XLS";

    private String reportId;
    private String defaultFormat; 
    private String reportName;

    public String getReportId() {
        return reportId;
    }

    public void setReportId(String reportId) {
        this.reportId = reportId;
    }

    public String getDefaultFormat() {
        return defaultFormat;
    }

    public void setDefaultFormat(String defaultFormat) {
        this.defaultFormat = defaultFormat;
    }

    public String getReportName() {
        return reportName;
    }

    public void setReportName(String reportName) {
        this.reportName = reportName;
    }

     public static String getFileFormat(String reportId){
        for(DefaultFormatE s : DefaultFormatE.values()){
            if(s.getReportId().equalsIgnoreCase(reportId)){
                return s.getDefaultFormat();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Listing.vue

```
<template>
  <!-- printing out report list from enum by for loop --!>
</template>

<script>
import Report  from '../enum/enumExample.java';//Is it the correct import way?

export default {

}
</script>

<style>
    
</style>
```

I want to print out all the report like this on my website:

| report id | report name | format |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Report001 | ReportName001 | HTML |
| Report002 | ReportName002 | PDF |
| Report003 | ReportName003 | XLS |

Answer (score 0):

You cannot directly access a `Java` class through `Vue`. You need to implement a rest API that will be accessed by `Vue`. Clearly we are talking about a full stack application with a `Front End` in `Vue` and the `Back End` in `Java`

Take a look [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2G6r2f40Lps).